# when i try to serialize object with symfony serializer i got some emty field (created_at and updated_at)?

Tags: php, json, api, symfony4, serialization

when i try to serialiaze a given object with symfony serializer i got some emty field 
what's the probleme with a datetime type.

```
$discussionList = $user->getDiscussions();
        $page = 1;
    $page = $request->get('page');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $last_list, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', $page)/*page number*/,
        $request->query->get('limit', 5)/*limit per page*/);
   $page_number= $pagination->getCurrentPageNumber();
   $item_number_per_page= $pagination->getItemNumberPerPage();
   $number_page= $pagination->getTotalItemCount()/5;
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer]);
    $data = $serializer->normalize([$pagination,
        array('current page'=>$page_number,
        'item number per page'=>$item_number_per_page,
            'total page' =>$number_page)],
        null, ['groups' => 'discussion']);
    return new JsonResponse($data,200);
```

here is my my code in my controller, and the returned response is this.

```
        {
        "id": 15,
        "createdAt": [],
        "updatedAt": [],
        "message": [
            {
                "id": 37,
                "contenu": "hello again from user 68",
                "created_at": [],
                "updated_at": [],
                "etat": 0,
                "user": {
                    "id": 68,
                    "first_name": "auxiliaire",
                    "second_name": "second_auxiliaire",
                    "profil_photo": "ae2d92cf6bf904f13153c3cc38fa1bbd.jpg"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution, maybe one day another person find the same problem that's why i share the solution

```
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
$serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer]);
```

just replace this with this 2 lignes.

```
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null);
    $serializer = new Serializer([new DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer]);
```